# Getting back in the waste exchange in batman arkham city.

Tags: batman-arkham-city

How would I get back into the waste exchange after the tower has been blown up?

Comment: Can you add a little more detail about where you are in the game? I haven't played it for awhile and don't remember the waste exchange. By "the tower", do you mean Wonder Tower? What is your current objective?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of to what you call "waste exchange" would be either the abandoned subway or Old Gotham under Wonder Tower, or the watery areas of the Sionis Steel Mill.

If you're referring to Wonder Tower, there are two entrances, which may not be accessible at certain points in the story.

> The first is the subway entrance from The Bowery - this opens when you're tasked to shut down Penguin's comms jammers. The second is a large round hole in the ground under a crane in the industrial zone (Joker's district); this opens when you're tracking one of Ras al Ghul's assassins. Both entrances are open long before, and after, Wonder Tower explodes.

The Steel Mill is accessed at first via a smokestack tower.

> This way is soon blocked. I forget exactly when, but it's okay - there's no need for you to return while you're on the trail of Freeze, Penguin, or Ras. Eventually, another entrance opens in the industrial district, at ground level. Then another entrance opens after Batman is rescued by Catwoman.